# C++ - Value to string matching?

Tags: c++, arrays, enums

I have a CD/DVD lib that detects the medium and responds with an integer. The value of the integer determines the type of medium such as the CD, DVD or BRD.

I was thinking of using a enum and matching the integer value to a enum value. I dont think that will work right

```
enum discTypes { UNKNOWN, CD-R, CD-RW, DVD-R, DVD-RW };
```

But I think a better way of doing it is making an array of values and returning that ?

```
QString discTypes[5] { UNKNOWN, CD-R, CD-RW, DVD-R, DVD-RW };
```

I was just looking for someone to chime in a little =)~ I'm open to a better solution as well.

Comment: You need to **map** the enum values to strings for representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. If you assign integers to the enum values, it will fall into place more cleanly:

```
enum discTypes { 
    UNKNOWN = 123, 
    CD_R = 234, 
    CD_RW = 52,
    DVD_R = 83, 
    DVD_RW = 934 
};
```

Then in your code:

```
diskTypes d = (diskTypes) GetValueFromMedia();
switch (diskTypes)
{
    case CD_R:
        // do something
        break;
}
```

The only problem here is if `GetValueFromMedia()` returns an invalid value; there's no automated way to verify it.

Answer (score 1):

The enum is perfectly fine, just use names withtout -.